# Compile C program with python

Tags: python, c, compiler-errors, compilation

I’m trying to write a code translator from my own programming language to C. Then I want to automatically compile the C program afterwards. However, somehow, the

```
import os
os.system(“clang main.c -o main”)
```

isn’t working. The compiler is complaining.

```
undefined reference to ‘main’ clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I edit the program by adding -v the output is not helpful at all.
I try compiling it by hand using the exact same command and somehow it works perfectly! I want this to be automatic. Please help me.

The original program is the classic hello world program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("HELLO");
}
```

My programming language’s repl is at
https://repl.it/@TechnologyDev/LexingtonToCWithPython#main.py
On the other hand,
https://repl.it/@TechnologyDev/CantCompileC#hello
is working.

Comment: How does your `main.c` look? Does it contain `main` function?

Comment: What is this output that _you_ didn't find helpful?

Comment: By the way, this is an unusual thing to do. Are you aware of tools like make, CMake, or (since you seem to like Python) SCons?

Comment: Does the generated file compile correctly if you try to compile it manually?  Is the generated file in the current working directory?

Comment: Works for me. This question does not contain enough information.

Comment: Your main function in C isn't returning zero

Comment: @AliShanoon Yes it is. It's just not explicit.

Comment: @Thomas I don’t want to add some other compiler, I just want to use the classic compilers I have, and I use clang.

Comment: And @JohnBode yes if I compile it manually it works perfectly fine, the main program is there, and when I run it, it displays “HELLO”.

Comment: @TechnologyDev Thomas asked you what the output is with `-v`. Please don't ignore questions from people trying to help you.

Comment: Make, CMake and SCons aren't compilers, they are build tools that invoke compilers. If you're just compiling one file, you don't really need them, but then you might as well use a shell script instead of Python. As your program grows more complex, a build tool become a virtual necessity.

Comment: @klutt I’m trying to get the output but I’m running on repl.it and I have some troubles with getting the output.

Comment: Also, exactly why do you want to compile a C program with a Python program?

Comment: Ah, I see. Well post it when you have it.

Comment: Because I’m writing my own programming language, and I decided it would be a nice challenge to translate the program to C and then compile it.

Comment: Well unfortunately  I cannot reproduce this. Tried this exact code, and compilation worked fine. Both in Python2 and Python3. My guess is that you're compiling another `main.c` than you think.

Comment: Is that the same file you compile? Are you executing your script in correct working directory?

Comment: Odd... I compile it in a separate repl and it works...

Comment: And yes. It is the same file and the same directory.

Comment: Try adding a `os.system(“cat main.c”)` call before the one that invokes `clang` and see if `main.c` is indeed the `main.c` you think it is.

Comment: Ok, will do. :)

Comment: Hmmm... maybe it’s good to mention that I’m doing a little file extension and sys.argv juggling, but the command is what I want it to be....

Comment: You should generate a unique temporary filename (e.g. a `/tmp/generated1234_0.c` the first time, and a `/tmp/generated1234_1.c` the second time, where 1234 is your pid)

Comment: Mmh, I already did a temphelloworld.c compile and it didn’t work on the program I need it to work, but it worked on the program that I don’t need it to work...